# Page title for real estate website

Tags: seo, ranking, title

When user creates a real-estate content page, the `title` will be created by the rules I will create.

Lets say there will be 10,000 flats on sale in London.

So to make this as good as I can - how do I make good rules for page `title` for all content created?

I would make tokens that will handle this something like:

```
"City" - "Type of real-estate + ft" - "price" - "Website name"
```

E.g.:

```
(London - Apartment 50ft - $120,000 - WEBSITE NAME)
```

I could probably think of something better if I had 5 - 10 flats, but when I know there will huge amount of them I have no idea which will work best.

The content has many fields which could be used for page title (address, postal, price, number of floors, parking lots etc.)

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
Flat for sale: [type of real estate] - [street name], [city], [post code] - [price]
```

I think this would pretty much cover any initial search criteria from the search results page when someone is searching for flats for sale.

Comment: I think there is no point for price up there (nobody really searches for "flat in hackney for 300000 pounds" on a search engine), although it should be prominent on the body of the page. The rest I think it's a very good page title.

Comment: Price not be searched for no but it is essential to whether a buyer will find out more about a property. If the price is out of their range then they can rule it out immediately. Placed at end of page title though due to the minimal importance.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Property type] [For (sale|rent)] in ([street]), [Area], [city], [postcode]
```

For example

```
2 bedroom flat for sale in Mare Street, Hackney, London, E5 0AB
```

Or a slight variation of this. At least this is how the main players do it.